# Set DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this in my model, the content is the full list of country :

```
public IList<LookupCountry> LookupCountry { get; set; };
public int SelectedCountry { get; set; }
```

The look like this

```
public class LookupCountry : ILookup
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string FR { get; set; }
}

public interface ILookup
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Code { get; set; }
    string FR { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I'd like show the country list and the selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.LookupCountry.Id,  
    new SelectList(Model.LookupCountry, 
    "Id", 
    "Value", 
    Model.SelectedCountry), 
    "-- Select Country --")
```

When I do this, I have en error, the **Id** in `c => c.LookupCountry.Id` is not available in the view.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `c.LookupCountry.Id` to `c.SelectedCountry` should do the trick. Since LookupCountry a collection of countries there is no Id property on it.  And you want to bind selected value from dropdown to `SelectedCountry` property.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCountry,  
    new SelectList(Model.LookupCountry, 
    "Id", 
    "Value", 
    Model.SelectedCountry), 
    "-- Select Country --")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `LookupCountry` in your model has type of `IList<LookupCountry>`. The list in whole does not contain for `id`, all of its members one by one contain `id`. Probably you want to rewrite your method as follows

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCountry,  
    new SelectList(Model.LookupCountry, 
    "Id", 
    "Value", 
    Model.SelectedCountry), 
    "-- Select Country --")
```